# Why would switching to Blackbox from GNOME turn off my internet?

Tags: internet, gnome

I got a hold of Blackbox because I felt like GNOME was eating up too much RAM.

The problem is, if I reboot, login with GNOME's login screen, and select Blackbox as the window manager, I don't have internet.  The routing table is empty and I can't get an IPv4 address with DHCP.

I can then log out ( from the session with Blackbox ), select GNOME, log in, and my internet is all set up.  Everything works.

I can then log out of the GNOME session, select Blackbox, log in, and my internet works.

So... I have to log in with GNOME just to get internet for some reason, but I don't know where to look.  How could I get internet with Blackbox without logging with GNOME first?

Comment: Do you really mean "_can't_ get an IP address", or do you actually mean "_won't_ get an IP address"? In other words, are you manually starting a DHCP client from Blackbox, or are you expecting that to happen all by itself?

Comment: Well, I tried to get an IP address with dhclient( ie. manually ), but there's no offers.  So, I was wondering how GNOME did it automatically, so I can put something together that runs when I start with Blackbox.

Comment: Are you talking about WiFi or Ethernet here?

Comment: Ethernet, `dhclient eth0`, when run with Blackbox, doesn't get offers....  That doesn't mean to imply Blackbox is stopping it, but somehow, GNOME can get internet, but Blackbox can't.

Comment: What do you use for the network in GNOME, then? NetworkManager?

Comment: It seems the command `nm-applet` is being used, in GNOME's start applications... I hope that answers whether or not it is NetworkManager, since I don't know how to answer that....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `NetworkManager.service` is active/running. My guess is that it's not "enabled" for automatic startup, but GNOME still launches it via DBus (but Blackbox of course doesn't).

`nm-applet` is optional, but still recommended, since it handles interactive prompts (e.g. Wi-Fi password prompts).

Comment: It seems, with Blackbox and my computer, `service network-manager start` results in `[ ok ] Starting network connection manager: NetworkManager already started.`  but still no internet :( might work for someone else though :D